# Separate instances of Vuex store clash each other when working across separate Vue instances

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am currently learning/prototyping vue.js and vuex (using plain js, at the moment).  I am trying to accomplish following:

- create multiple vue instances having their own vuex stores independent to each other.  Right now, I am storing only ajax status/progress in vuex store and improve it gradually.
- vue instances can come from same vue definition (template, methods etc.), but need to work with different vuex store instances.
- vuex stores should not know about each other (no clashes) and should only work exclusively with their respective vue instance counter parts.

I almost achieved the above as shown below:

index.html - https://gist.github.com/guywithdoubts/2f64346929a3d8adec79a1cd927e39a8

app.html (template) - https://gist.github.com/guywithdoubts/c09298a8e593705d73f19bf8427cfcf7

app.js (vue def. 1) - https://gist.github.com/guywithdoubts/66b99fabe1d1a3f15c18914b8cf64e6d

app2.js (vue def. 2) - https://gist.github.com/guywithdoubts/bda070fdebfcc8756ce80ead6e5dcd09

Theoritically, we can just create one class out of app.js and app2.js (identical code).  But, just to test/troubleshoot things, I separated them.

I am able to pull data and everything seems working fine.  if I hit refresh button in second instance, I get the following log (which is perfect, as everything is happening in app2 related store):

[image]

But, if I hit refresh button in first instance, I get the following log:

[image]

The first vue instance (from app.js) is working/clashing with vuex store related to second vue instance (from app2.js).

I am not sure on where I am going wrong on this.  Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: ever heared about vuex modules? https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#modules

Comment: heard about that.  But not sure if it is going to work in my case (as it is like two different apps without one knowing about other)

Comment: jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/9rLp5t4s/

Comment: I don't get what the use case for this is. Why do you want multiple Vue instances to act on the same `index.html`?

Comment: Why not.  We can use the same template for multiple Vue instances.  That's how I see in documentation.  It's a kind of reusing same template for multiple component instances.  Let me if I am mistaken